# Is there a possibility to get Photoshop's field blur inside After Effects ? (or something similar)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-after-effects

What I really want is to add shading to my animated shape layers.

I'd love to have something working like Photoshop's field blur, who can easily add varying degrees of blur on a single layer.

> Use Field Blur to build a gradient of blurs, by defining multiple blur points with different amounts of blur. Add multiple pins to the image and specify a blur amount for each pin.
>
> The final result is combined effect of all blur pins on the image. You can even add a pin outside the image, to apply the blur at corners.

That can be really useful to smooth out shadow layers without having a uniform gradient.

Hope you see what I mean.

[More info about Photoshop's field blur on Adobe Help.](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blur-gallery.html)

I stumbled upon [Eyedsyn's Shade it plug-in](http://www.eyedesyn.com/product/shade-it-for-after-effects/) but it looks just like an emboss effect and it seems it can only make noisy shading.

I don't mind that much about a noisy effect though.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that [Red Giant's Universe Spot Blur](https://www.redgiant.com/universe/universe-tools/) does pretty much the same!

It's one of the lastest at the bottom of the page.